# Audio and video stream player

Tags: ios, iphone, audio, video, photo

I need to play Audio and video stream from Vk.com and youtube. And also I need phoro browser. Is there any usefull libs for this?

Answer (score 0):

you should use JW flv player. They provide all options like xml file for source audio or video files.

follow this link 
http://www.jwplayer.com/